# What this error is "+[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1c864a0' "?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am writing a simple code that is using NSTimer, but getting error as followed

"+[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x1c864a0'"

my Code is

```
-(void)myTimerMethod {

    NSLog(@"myTimerMethod is Called");
    
  myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
}


-(void) targetMethod:(NSTimer*) theTimer {
    NSLog(@"Me is here at 1 minute delay");
}
```

and I am making object of of Timer class in my appDelegate.m like as following

```
Timer *myTimer = [[Timer alloc] init];
[myTimer myTimerMethod];
```

What is the problem in it?

Comment: Justin answered the only problem apparent in the clues you have posted so far.   Post more info;  the exact error, the exact code, something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the method is misnamed as declared. it is:

```
+ (NSTimer *)scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds target:(id)target selector:(SEL)aSelector userInfo:(id)userInfo repeats:(BOOL)repeats
```

Comment: @ Justin, I check it, name is correct, but I am having one warning at scheduledTimerWithInterval, this is warning "'NSTimer' may not respond to '+scheduledTimerWithInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:'
"

Comment: Veer, you're missing 'Time' - it's scheduledTimerWith**Time**Interval.

Comment: oops, sorry about that, i was referencing two separate methods in my initial reply. response updated

Comment: @rcw3 I am putting it 1 as like this "myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];"

Comment: @Veer it's `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:`, not `scheduledTimerWithInterval:`

Answer (score 0):

This code perfectly working, check it out, just copy and paste the code.

@implementation Timer

-(void)myTimerMethod
{
    NSLog(@"myTimerMethod is Called");
     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
}

-(void) targetMethod:(NSTimer*) theTimer { NSLog(@"Me is here at 1 minute delay"); }

@end

In app delegate call

Timer *myTimer = [[Timer alloc] init];

[myTimer myTimerMethod];

Comment: corr: Me is here at 1 *second* delay